# What quality caulks are available in the United States of America?

Tags: caulk

I have heard numerous bad things about [DAP® ALEX® Painters Caulk](http://www.dap.com/product_details.aspx?BrandID=11&SubcatID=3) cracking etc.  Looking for suggestions what some better quality caulk is that is preferably paintable without primer and is available in the U.S..

Comment: What have you heard about DAP Alexa?  Why is it not suitable for your project?

Comment: I have heard it cracks too soon

Comment: I've never had that problem, and have been using it for years.

Comment: We have all qualities of caulks.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us a bit about the application, and why Alex isn't appropriate.  We could then recommend an alternative.

Comment: See the [meta discussion](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/607/2196) for more details about our product recommendation policy.

Answer (score 1):

We have several good/better lines of caulking available depending on your given project.

I worked at Lowes in the paint department for over 4 years total. Never had anyone bring back anything other than DAP...strange. We even had a rack specifically for returned products and mis-tint paints, filled with DAP.

Anyway, there are a few good brands that I've personally used that get my pick for this forum:

GE - general purpose, adhesive, and sealant properties GE makes some good caulk. Latex or PolyUrethane
3M - great specialty caulking, had to use this on the bottom of a sea-ray one time, stuff is amazing and is still holding to this day...
Loctite - great sealant and polyurethane caulking for outdoor use, specifically the ones marked 'PL' are the ones I've used.

Hope this helps...

Comment: thanks.  should i even bother trying Lowes/HD or should i go straight to a specialty paint store?

Comment: For variety, I would say Lowes is a great place to start, in my experience (and not because I work there) Lowe's employees are generally more concerned with helping you vs stocking, but only cause I've been to HD so many times and their CS is terrible out here...However, I'm sure Benjamin Moore or Sherwin Williams would have a couple nice ones to fit your project. Best of luck!

Comment: you could also select my answer as the correct one if i helped you out!~ thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I started using GE paintable silicone about 10 years ago and have had no problems. Prior to that I used various types of caulk with unsatisfactory results. It costs more, but its well worth it to me. I use it mostly outside on the gaps between the siding and corner 2x4's and the gaps between the masonite siding.

[image: GE 9-oz White Silicone Window and Door Caulk]